# Set string for empty tag in NSXMLParse iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, set, string

I want to set string "EMPTY"for empty tag XML in NSXMLParse. Exm: my xml:

```
<STATE>0</STATE>
<MEMO/>
```

In above XML, MEMO tag is empty. I want to when NSXMLParse parse into  tag, if it is empty,get string "EMPTY" in label. I used bellow code to parse xml:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"Did start element");
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"FILENAME"])
    {
        XML_FIELD = FILENAME_CLOUD2;
        NSLog(@"found rootElement");

        return;
    }
    else if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"MEMO"])
    {
        NSLog(@"found rootElement");
        XML_FIELD = MEMO;
        return;
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

           NSLog(@"Did end element");
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"FILENAME"])
        {
            NSLog(@"rootelement end");
        }
        [strMemoEmpty setString:@"EMPTY"];
        XML_FIELD = UNIMPORTANT2;


}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    //NSString *tagName = @"USER_NAME";

    if (XML_FIELD == FILENAME_CLOUD2)
    {
        NSLog(@"Value %@",string);
        [FileCompletedArray insertObject:string atIndex:0];

    }
    else if (XML_FIELD == MEMO)
    {
        NSLog(@"Value %@",string);
        if (string != nil) {
            [strMemoEmpty setString:@""];
            [strMemoEmpty appendString: string];
            NSLog(@"foundResults: %@",strMemoEmpty);
        }
            [MemoArray insertObject:string atIndex:0];
    }
}
```

I used above code but it not check MEMO tag is empty. It missed when parse. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't really used NSXMLParser but to my understanding is that your attempting to set a string to 'EMPTY' when an xml tag is EMPTY. If possible, you should look at TBXML, it is one of the fastest and most efficient xml parser for iOS applications. I use it with the ASIHTTPREQUEST library, but i hear theres no more updates for ASIHTTPREQUEST - a library that subclasses NSURLConnection and makes implementing asyncronous calls much easier, which is generally better for large amounts of data to be parsed and analyzed. Sorry this answer isn't exactly a good ANSWER, but it is a comment :)

Comment: So what your saying is <MEMO/> is not being read in by NSXMLParser? If possible, please include the start tag and end tag of the xml service your attempting to parse... Usually there should be a starting tag and ending tag... e.g. <MEMO></MEMO>... just like <STATE>0</STATE>

Comment: @jsetting32: thanks but i can't edit data xml of server response. I only want how get string of <MEMO/>. DO you show me ?

Comment: oh i mean can you copy and paste the REST of the xml response. Or is the <MEMO/> tag the only one in the xml response?

Comment: @jsetting32: it is child tag of <File> tag. And xml response have many <File? tag

Comment: hmm.. I'll try to create a similar scenario and solve it... Hopefully ill have something for you sometime tomorrow. but if you do solve the issue please post the answer, i'd like to see how you did it. sorry i can't give you an answer now but maybe you should look into TBXML parser while you wait or just continue to look at stack overflow questions that relate to your question. It's a great parser - TBXML...

Comment: Show all the code. How are you handling the found characters?

Comment: I posted code in foundCharater() @Wain

Answer (score 0):

The construction of your code is a bit strange and messy, you should reorganise so:

1. `didStartElement` creates new storage for the starting element and sets any flags
2. `foundCharacters` doesn't have logic, it just appends the received string to a mutable buffer (it could be called multiple times for the same tag)
3. `didEndElement` contains the logic (and checks the length of the found characters and substitutes your empty value if required)

The way you have it now means that partial data may be saved in `foundCharacters` and, because that method isn't called for empty tags, some of your logic is being set but never actually saved.